# Why do we have two different Elastic Modulus in Tension and Torsion?

Tags: solid-mechanics, elastic-modulus

I was trying to get a value for elastic modulus for 316L stainless steel material from internet, and I saw a brochure online which was giving two different values for elastic modulus, one in tension and one in torsion. I was confused why this is the case?

Comment: Can you provide the link to the online brochure?

Comment: There are many elastic moduli: Young's (axial), shear (torsion), bulk (volumetric), biaxial, plane-strain, P-wave, complex...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the value for the torsion related modulus for 316L should be close to 79[GPa], compared to 200-210 [GPa] for tension.

The shear modulus for isotropic materials can be analytically calculated as

$$G = \frac{E}{2\cdot(1+\nu)}$$

where:

- G is the shear modulus
- E is the tensile modulus
- $\nu$ is the Poisson's ratio.

You can see a derivation in the following [link (University of Auckland)](http://homepages.engineering.auckland.ac.nz/%7Epkel015/SolidMechanicsBooks/Part_I/BookSM_Part_I/06_LinearElasticity/06_Linear_Elasticity_Complete.pdf)